# Objective C: NavigationBar for PageViewController

Tags: objective-c, uipageviewcontroller

I have a `UITableViewController` was added to a `UIPageViewController` as the pages, the program push `PageViewController` and show `UINavigationBar` on the top of the `PageViewController`, I want to add `UIBarButton` to `UINavigationBar` to control `UITableViewCells`, but can only do it on the screen of `PageViewController`, that means, all events related to this button must be handle in `PageViewController`, because all these events are related to `TableView cell` controls, I want them are handled in `UITableViewController`.

I tried many ways, like define a `IBOutlet` in `UITableViewController`, and when `viewDidLoad`, set `self.NavigationItem rightitem` to this `IBOutlet` item, all did not work.

Comment: is there any navigation controller for tableview controller or page view controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how you're creating the `UINavigationController` but I assume you're doing it from `PageViewController`. If that's the case, then make sure that the `PageViewController` pushes onto the `UINavigationController` the `UITableViewController`. You cannot add the `UITableViewController` to the `PageViewController`.

In other words, the `PageViewController` creates a page with a `UINavigationController`. Then you push onto `UINavigationController` the `UITableViewController`.

At that point when inside your subclassed `UITableViewController`, you should have access to `self.navigationItem`, etc...